# How to merge rows that have the same values on my dynamic table with some conditions using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

My goal is to merge rows for the first 3 columns of my table but if the first column has a different value, my second column should not merge.

To visualize better here is my current table:

https://imgur.com/uGcr54O

And I want to make it look like this:

https://imgur.com/8ibuvoU

As you can see on the first image, BBB1 is merged 4x because it appeared on my query 4x, but since it has a different value on the first column, I need to merge it like it shows on the 2nd image.

Here's my current code:

```
<script>
        var table = document.getElementById('myTable');

        function mergeCells(table, startIndex) {
          let headerCell = null;

          for (let row of table.rows) {
            const firstCell = row.cells[startIndex];

            if (headerCell === null || firstCell.innerText !== headerCell.innerText) {
              headerCell = firstCell;
            } else {
              headerCell.rowSpan++;
              firstCell.remove();
            }
          }
        }
        mergeCells(table, 2);
        mergeCells(table, 1);
        mergeCells(table, 0);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can merge cells in one column only if the corresponding cells in all previous columns have also been merged. The following code works recursively: after mergeable cells from row M to row N in one column have been determined, it invokes itself to process the cells in these rows in the next column and only then merges the mergeable cells.

```js
function mergeCells(table, startCol, endCol, startRow, endRow) {
  let cell, cellStart;

  function mergeCell(r) {
    if (cell && r > cellStart + 1) {
      if (startCol < endCol)
        mergeCells(table, startCol + 1, endCol, cellStart, r);
      cell.rowSpan = r - cellStart;
      for (let s = cellStart + 1; s < r; s++)
        table.rows[s].cells[startCol].remove();
    }
  }
  for (let r = startRow; r < endRow; r++) {
    const curCell = table.rows[r].cells[startCol];
    if (!cell || cell.textContent !== curCell.textContent) {
      mergeCell(r);
      cell = curCell;
      cellStart = r;
    }
  }
  mergeCell(endRow);
}
const table = document.getElementById('myTable');
mergeCells(table, 0, 2, 1, table.rows.length);
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
    <th>Column 3</th>
    <th>Column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AAAA</td>
    <td>BBBB</td>
    <td>CCCC</td>
    <td>DDDD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AAAA</td>
    <td>BBBB</td>
    <td>CCCC</td>
    <td>DDDD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AAA1</td>
    <td>BBB1</td>
    <td>CCC1</td>
    <td>DDD2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AAA1</td>
    <td>BBB1</td>
    <td>CCC1</td>
    <td>DDD3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AAA2</td>
    <td>BBB1</td>
    <td>CCC3</td>
    <td>DDD4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>AAA2</td>
    <td>BBB1</td>
    <td>CCC3</td>
    <td>DDD5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your code works perfect! It's interesting how you played around with the code and made it recursive. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I changed condition to concatenate current column text and previous column text, and compare with next row like "AAA1BBB1" === "AAA2BBB1".
I think make more simply using jquery.

```
<script>
  var table = document.getElementById('myTable');

  function mergeCells(table, startIndex) {
    let headerCell = null;

    for (let [idx, row] of Object.entries(table.rows)) {
      const firstCell = row.cells[startIndex];
      const prevCell = row.cells[startIndex - 1];
      const lower = table.rows[[parseInt(idx) + 1]];
      const next_firstCell = lower?.cells[startIndex];
      const next_prevCell = lower?.cells[startIndex - 1];

      const cur = prevCell?.innerText + firstCell.innerText;
      const next = next_prevCell?.innerText + next_firstCell?.innerText;

      if (headerCell === null || cur === next) {
        headerCell = firstCell;
      } else {
        headerCell.rowSpan++;
        firstCell.remove();
      }
    }
  }
  mergeCells(table, 2);
  mergeCells(table, 1);
  mergeCells(table, 0);
</script>
```

Comment: I tried using your code and it seems that it does not work properly since my column 1 is not merging anymore and I've been getting duplicates on my other columns. The answer by @heiko already fixed my problem and I appreciate your help!